# I can't find the reason for "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" error

Tags: java, string, for-loop

My code takes the first and last words of a user input and turns them into uppercase. However, when the user enters "" or "java"(word without spaces) an error pops up. I could not find the reason for the error.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = input.nextLine();

    String first = "";
    String last = "";

    String end = s;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i<s.length()-1;i++) {

        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {

            count++;

        }
        if (count == 0) {

            end = s.toUpperCase();
        }

        else if (count > 0) 

        first = s.substring(0,s.indexOf(' '));
        last = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);

        end = (first.toUpperCase() + " " + s.substring(first.length()+1,s.indexOf(last)) + " " +last.toUpperCase());

    }


    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: I would print the lentth of s and the length of first within your else-clause. I think it would probably tell you.

Comment: Split the words using String.split(" ") and store in to start and end string as per requirement and convert it to uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String first = s.substring(0,s.indexOf(' '));
String last = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
```

Your code here is causing the problem. If a space is not present in your `String` then `indexOf(' ')` will return -1. You obviously can't substring between 0 and -1. You need to check if `' '` is present in the `String` before you substring it.

Comment: I edited it, unfortunately still gives me an error. I am sure it is about the part you mentioned, but even when I check, it gives an error.

Comment: You'e doing the same thing in your last line before your print.  Buried in there is `s.substring(first.length()+1,s.indexOf(last))`.

Comment: I should clarify that the issue here is that `s.indexOf(last)` is returning zero, and `substring()` gets the string from `start` to `end - 1`, so that end index is becoming -1 in there.